# How can I use node-soap in Meteorjs?

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-soap

I would like to use node-soap in Meteorjs.
In the github readme, I see the example:

```
server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
      response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
  });
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', myService, "xml");
```

But I don't know how can I do this in meteor, as I can't create server instance.
Does anyone know, how can I get server instance from Meteor?

Comment: Have you found an answer ? [meteor-soap](https://github.com/zardak/meteor-soap/) only supports the client mode. Using the [NPM package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) to bridge to the official meteor-soap might be an option but does not look very nice. Cheating with [http-methods](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods) is an option as well but we have to handle the wsdl protocol ourselves then.

Comment: I used cheating with http-methods :)
I had simple wsdl, so I could parse messages myself.